# Rails Action Mailer TLS Certificate Issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use rackspace ssl smtp for my mail settings for our rails application and I am receiving this error

hostname was not match with the server certificate

I need to find a way to disable verify on the certs for ActionMailer.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved issue by using sendmail and configuring sendmail to use the proper smtp settings required to use rackspace email hosting.

Comment: how do we configure sendmail the way you said?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting enable_starttls_auto to false in your smtp_settings:

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true
ActionMailer::Base.default_charset = "utf-8"

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address => 'server.com',
  :port => '25',
  :domain => 'yourdomain.com',
  :user_name => 'username',
  :password => 'password',
  :authentication => :login,
  :enable_starttls_auto => false
}
```

Comment: Tried this, sorry to be so long on this response but it doesnt work as rackspace requires tls. Best option is to use sendmail and configure sendmail to use the rackspace tls smtp server.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I can't comment on Derek's answer, but his answer does in fact work now with Rackspace. Simply changing tls to false now works great.