# In Rails 3 and ActionMailer, is it possible to send email using TLS over SSL (Not StartTLS)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I would like to use ActionMailer to send emails from my rail app.  I have an existing mail server that I would like to use, however it only supports SSL/TLS on port 465.  It does not, however, support StartTLS (typically on port 587).

Can anyone suggest a way of achieving this?  As far as I can tell there is no support out of the box for this.  I am using Rails 3.0.7.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you can specify the :ssl option.

Set the following values in your `config/environments/production.rb` file:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: 'mail.example.com',
    port: 465,
    domain: 'example.com',
    user_name: 'no-reply@example.com',
    password: 'password',
    authentication: 'plain',
    ssl: true,
}
```

This works with my ISP (Bluehost) for sending mail.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I am aware of at this time is monkey patching the SMTP module

http://treadpath.typepad.com/thoughtintomotion/2011/06/actionmailer-woes-integrating-with-rackspaces-email-service.html

Comment: Actually this looks like the better solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040567/rails-action-mailer-tls-certificate-issues